# Use math symbols in panel titles for stratigraphic plot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to include math symbols in the panel titles for this stratigraphic plot:

```
library(analogue)
data(V12.122)
Depths <- as.numeric(rownames(V12.122))
names(V12.122)

(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   zones = 400))

plt
```

[image]

For example, I want to have this text in place of "O.univ" etc.:

[image]

I used this code to make that text:

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
title(line = -1, main = expression(phantom()^14*C~years~BP))
title(line = -3, main = expression(delta^18*O))
title(line = -5, main = expression(paste("TP ", mu,"g l"^-1)))
title(line = -10, main = expression("very long title \n with \n line breaks"))
```

But if I try to update the colnames of the data frame passed to `Stratiplot`, the code is not parsed, and we do not get the correct text formatting:

```
V12.122 <- V12.122[, 1:4] 
names(V12.122)[1] <- expression(phantom()^14*C~years~BP)
names(V12.122)[2] <- expression(delta^18*O)
names(V12.122)[3] <- expression(paste("TP ", mu,"g l"^-1))

(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ .,
                   data = V12.122,  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   zones = 400))

plt
```

[image]

How can I get `Stratiplot` to parse the expressions in the colnames and format them correctly in the plot?

I've tried looking through `str(plt)` to see where the panel titles are stored, but no success:

```
text <- expression(phantom()^14*C~years~BP)
plt$condlevels$ind[1] <-  text
names(plt$packet.sizes)[1] <-  text
names(plt$par.settings$layout.widths$panel)[1] <-  text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually do this in the current release of **analogue**; the function is doing too much messing around with data for the expressions to remain unevaluated prior to plotting. I could probably figure this out to allow expressions as the `names` of the `data` argument object, but it is easier to just allow users to pass a vector of labels that they want for the variables.

This is [now implemented](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/analogue/commit/9466a511d929723c53deeb162a1a5129ae228b07) in the development version of the package on github, and I'll push this to CRAN early next week.

This change implements a new argument `labelValues` which takes a vector of labels for use in labelling the top axis. This can be a vector of expressions.

Here is an illustration of the usage:

```
library("analogue")
set.seed(1)
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200 * 3), ncol = 3)),
               c("d13C", "d15N", "d18O"))
df <- transform(df, Age = 1:200)
exprs <- expression(delta^{13}*C,  # label for 1st variable
                    delta^{15}*N,  # label for 2nd variable
                    delta^{18}*O)  # label for 3rd variable
Stratiplot(Age ~ ., data = df, labelValues = exprs, varTypes = "absolute", type = "h")
```

which produces

[image]

Note that this is just a first pass; I'm pretty sure I haven't accounted for any reordering that goes on with `sort` and `svar` etc. if they are used.

Comment: Always love when feature additions are borne out of a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Never used lattice plots, but I thought a chance to learn something should be worth while. Took too long to figure out.

```
text <- "c( expression(phantom()^14*C~years~BP),expression(delta^18*O))"

strip = strip.custom(factor.levels=eval(parse(text=text)))

plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ .,
                   data = V12.122[, 1:4],  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   zones = 400, 
                   strip = strip)
```

[image]

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: something to do with `par.strip.text` in the arguments to `xyplot`?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I don't want any text in the strips, I want to alter the text above each panel. I can't see where in `str(plt)` those labels are stored!

Comment: They're definitely not in there, they are in the optional arguments to the call to `xyplot` within the default `Stratiplot` method. Found it perusing the code in the package using `getAnywhere("Stratiplot.default")`.

Comment: The labels are accessed in the environment of `plt$axis` - the code uses the levels of `sx`, which is the stacked data object. It's probably best not to fiddle with this - and not easy nor user-friendly to do so. I've added an argument that will let you control this. Answer coming.